# react native programmatically open DrawerLayoutAndroid

Tags: react-native

I am using the DrawerLayoutAndroid and struggling to work out how to programmatically open and close it.

I see that you are supposed to use

openDrawer(0)but how do you reference the DrawerLayoutAndroid

I have a drawer that I have made exactly like in the docs, then I have a button on my View that if you press it I want it to open the DrawerLayoutAndroid

I created this function

```
toggleDrawer(){
  openDrawer(0);
};
```

but that obviously doesnt work, and just throws an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use refs for this. I am pasting the example here for your reference

```
    var DrawerExample = React.createClass({

        openDrawer:function() {
            this.refs['myDrawer'].openDrawer();
        },

        closeDrawer:function() {
            this.refs['myDrawer'].closeDrawer();
        },

        render: function() {
            var navigationView = (
                <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
                    <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'left'}}>I'm in the Drawer!</Text>

                    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.closeDrawer}>
                        <Text>{'Close Drawer'}</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>

                </View>
            );
            return (
                <DrawerLayoutAndroid ref="myDrawer"
                    drawerWidth={300}
                    drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
                    renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}>
                    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center'}}>
                        <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right'}}>Hello</Text>
                        <Text style={{margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: 'right'}}>World!</Text>

                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.openDrawer}>
                            <Text>{'Open Drawer'}</Text>
                        </TouchableHighlight>

                    </View>
                </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
            );
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
you have to Use
```

**ref={_drawer => (this.drawer = _drawer)}**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  DrawerLayoutAndroid,
  TouchableHighlight
} from "react-native";
export default class DrawerExample extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.openDrawer = this.openDrawer.bind(this);
  }

  openDrawer() {
    this.drawer.openDrawer();
  }

  render() {
    var navigationView = (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
        <Text style={{ margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: "left" }}>
          I'm in the Drawer!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
    return (
      <DrawerLayoutAndroid
        drawerWidth={300}
        ref={_drawer => (this.drawer = _drawer)}
        drawerPosition={DrawerLayoutAndroid.positions.Left}
        renderNavigationView={() => navigationView}
      >
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Text style={{ margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: "right" }}>
            Hello
          </Text>
          <Text style={{ margin: 10, fontSize: 15, textAlign: "right" }}>
            World!
          </Text>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.openDrawer}>
            <Text>{"Open Drawer"}</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain why your code would work.

Comment: I have use ref to open Drawer 
  
ref={_drawer => (this.drawer = _drawer)}
 openDrawer() {
    this.drawer.openDrawer();
  }

Comment: Works for me. Note: the answer works only for not a typescript project format.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to open it programmatically from a component (a View, for example) that is INSIDE the drawerlayoutandroid, you will need to call the function openDrawer() but with ".bind(this)". Otherwise, you won't be able to make it work, even using refs (that you will need to use anyway, as Jagadish wrote). I had that problem for a few days till I found out what I just wrote. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I did know that already from using normal functions inside the View, but I will give you an up tick anyways because it may help other people

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it using functional components and React.context:

Create a drawer context:

```
//DrawerContext.ts

import React from 'react';

export const DrawerContext = React.createContext<{
    isOpen: boolean;
    open: () => void;
    close?: () => void;
}>({
    isOpen: null,
    // close: null,
    open: null,
});
```

Then in your app:

```
export const SideMenu: React.FC = (props) => {

    const drawerRef = useRef<DrawerLayoutAndroid>();
    const [drawerIsOpen, setDrawerIsOpen] = useState(false);
 
    useEffect(() => {
        drawerRef.current.openDrawer(); //open drawer when app loads
        setDrawerIsOpen(true);
    }, []);
    return (
            <DrawerLayoutAndroid
                drawerWidth={300}
                renderNavigationView={() => <SideMenuItems />}
                drawerBackgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
                ref={drawerRef} //get the ref to the drawer
            >
                {/* Pass down the references using the context provider */}
                <DrawerContext.Provider value={{
                    open: () => drawerRef?.current?.openDrawer(),
                    isOpen: drawerIsOpen
                }}>
                    {props.children}
                </DrawerContext.Provider>
            </DrawerLayoutAndroid>
        )
}
```

And finally, consume the context in any of the children components:

```
//MyComponent.ts
import {DrawerContext} from './DrawerContext.ts'
...
export const MyComponent: React.FC = (props) => {
    const { open, isOpen, } = useContext(DrawerContext);
    return(
        ...
        <Button onPress={open}>Open Drawer!!</Button>
        ...
    )

}
```